# How to send an image from SFDC to .net application on the click of a button in .net

Tags: integration, .net

I have a requirement to show an image in .net application by making a query on Salesforce.

As a work around, i did write a simple webservice call in SFDC, but at the .net end I am getting the URL of the image.

But my requirement is to display the image of a click of a button on .net application.

Can someone suggest me something here to get this done.

Comment: Why it is a 'workaround'?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me.

Assuming that you want to store the image in Salesforce but present it in a HTML page of a .Net application then one way is for the image to be stored in Salesforce as Document that has "Externally Available Image" checked. The image is then available (with no authentication required) at the URL https://c.INSTANCE.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=DOCID&oid=ORGID where you need to set the appropriate INSTANCE, DOCID and ORGID values. The DOCID and ORGID values (or the entire URL) could be obtained via a webservice call. The URL is then directly used as the src of the image in the HTML.

Or do you want to transfer the image data (represented by the Blob type in Salesforce) from Salesforce server to .Net server? Or do something else?